# Raspberry Pi RuntimeError: Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO channel

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi3

I was following a tutorial found here:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/prepare-your-raspberry-pi-work-aws-iot-kay-lerch

I have not even begun the internet part of it as I was having issues with the circuit. I wired my circuit just like it is shown in this diagram below using my raspberry pi 3.
[image]

I then wrote the following python script as shown in the tutorial.

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(7, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)

def on_pushdown(channel):
        print "Button Pushed."

while(True):
        gpio.add_event_detect(7, gpio.RISING, callback=on_pushdown, bouncetime=200)
gpio.cleanup()
```

This should print out "Button Pushed" when I push the button but I get the following runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "button.py", line 10, in <module>
    gpio.add_event_detect(7, gpio.RISING, callback=on_pushdown, bouncetime=200)
RuntimeError: Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO channel
```

I have RPi.GPIO version 0.6.2 which is the latest version at the time o fthis post. I would appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have is adding an event detection callback constantly (in the `while(True)` loop). What you want is to add the event detection callback once and then wait for an edge.

This [page](http://raspi.tv/2014/rpi-gpio-update-and-detecting-both-rising-and-falling-edges) has a good example you might want to go through.

Alternatively, you could try something like:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(7, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)

def on_pushdown(channel):
    print "Button Pushed."

# only add the detection call once!
gpio.add_event_detect(7, gpio.RISING, callback=on_pushdown, bouncetime=200)

while(True):
    try:
        # do any other processing, while waiting for the edge detection
        sleep(1) # sleep 1 sec
    finally:
        gpio.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Doddie's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126203/3383640) answer has the problem that the program exits after the first button press. Since the author mentioned an eternal loop, I would like to propose the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

pin = 7 

def on_pushdown(channel):
    print "Button Pushed."

try:
    # Setting GPIO layout
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
    # Set pin as input pin pulled down to GND
    gpio.setup(pin, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)

    while True:
        if not 'event' in locals():
            event = gpio.add_event_detect(pin, gpio.RISING, callback=on_pushdown, bouncetime=200)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

finally:  
    gpio.cleanup()
```

If the button is pressed and an event is detected, the variable `event` is being deleted. Hence, the `add_event_detect`-function is not called twice in a row.

Additionally two things:

1. Depending on your setup, I would use a pull-up resistor. A pull-down setup is more prone to noise and an induction flank from somewhere might be interpreted as a button press.
2. Although this is **not best practice**: If your setup is really small (like inside the RPi case) and you don't accidentally set `gpio.OUT` and you just have a push button, you might consider to just take the build-in pull-up resistor and directly connect the push button to GND: `GND --/ -- GPIO.IN` (and then detect for `gpio.FALLING`).