# AlarmSystem with the RPi (python3) RuntimeError: Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO channel

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to make an Alarm Sytsm with the RPi in Python3. but there are two errors that come up after the second attempt.
This is the full code (writed in the ThonnyIDE):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import pygame
import itertools
import threading
import sys
import os


GPIO.setwarnings(False)

SENSOR_PIN = 23
rot = 4
gruen = 17
blau = 27

#GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(rot, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(gruen, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(blau, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.IN) 


done = False
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rLaden... ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write('\rFertig! ')

t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
t.start()

time.sleep(5)
done = True
time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write('\rWillkommen\n ')

def aktiv_ierung(): 
 while True:
  GPIO.output(blau, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(rot, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH) 
  an = input('CODE EINGEBEN UM ALARM ZU AKTIVIEREN: ')   
  if an == '123':
   pygame.mixer.init()
   pygame.mixer.music.load("aktiv.mp3")
   pygame.mixer.music.play()
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
   time.sleep(0.50)
   GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
   time.sleep(1.00)
   GPIO.output(rot, GPIO.HIGH)
   print('ALARMANLAGE SCHARF')
   try:
     GPIO.add_event_detect(SENSOR_PIN , GPIO.RISING , callback=mein_callback)
     while True:
        time.sleep(1)

   except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
        print('ALARM DEAKTIVIERT')

def mein_callback(channel):
 GPIO.output(rot, GPIO.LOW)
 GPIO.output(blau, GPIO.HIGH)
 print('Bewegung erkannt! 5 sek.')
 time.sleep(5)
 pygame.init()
 pygame.mixer.music.load("alarm.mp3")
 pygame.mixer.music.play()
 alarmaus = input('CODE EINGEBEN UM ALARM ZU DEAKTIVIEREN:')
 if alarmaus == '123':
     pygame.mixer.music.load("mute.mp3")
     GPIO.output(blau, GPIO.LOW)
     GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
     print('Alarmanlage deaktiviert')
     time.sleep(2)
     aktiv_ierung()  

aktiv_ierung()
```

This are the errors that come up:

1. ````
   File "/home/pi/Desktop/Alarmanlage/AlarmEXPERIMENT.py", line 104, in mein_callback
   aktiv_ierung() ```
   ````
2. ````
   GPIO.add_event_detect(SENSOR_PIN , GPIO.RISING , callback=mein_callback)
   RuntimeError: Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO channel```
   ````

Please dont close this. I need exact help.
This doesnt work: [Raspberry Pi RuntimeError: Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125047/raspberry-pi-runtimeerror-conflicting-edge-detection-already-enabled-for-this-g)

Greetings

Comment: The message is implying you should only call `add_event_detect` once in your code. Now it's called every time in `aktiv_ierung()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to really tell what your alarm system should be doing, but here's a simplified version (that omits the code entry bits).

The idea here is that you set up your input GPIO pins exactly once per your program, and the `sensor_callback` only sets a threading event that the main loop in `loop()` waits for; when the event is set, music is played and [blinkenlights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights) get blinked.

Per the comments, blinkenlights are now blinkened via a background thread.

```py
import threading
import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import pygame

SENSOR_PIN = 23
RED_PIN = 4
GREEN_PIN = 17
BLUE_PIN = 27

trip_event = threading.Event()
quit_event = threading.Event()
blink_lights = False


def reset_lights():
    global blink_lights
    GPIO.output(BLUE_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(RED_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(GREEN_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
    blink_lights = False


def blinkenlights_thread_callback():
    # Loop until told to quit.
    while not quit_event.wait(0.25):
        for x in range(5):
            if not blink_lights:  # Allow interrupting the blink cycle.
                break
            GPIO.output(GREEN_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(0.50)
            GPIO.output(GREEN_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.50)


def sensor_callback(channel):
    trip_event.set()


def prompt_code_until_correct(prompt, correct_code):
    while True:
        if input(prompt) == correct_code:
            break
        print("Incorrect code.")


def loop():
    global blink_lights
    # (1) Prompt for activation code
    prompt_code_until_correct("Enter activation code:", "123")
    trip_event.clear()  # In case the sensor was tripped during prompt.

    # (2) Wait until the alarm is tripped
    while True:
        trip_event.wait(timeout=0.5)
        if trip_event.is_set():
            trip_event.clear()
            reset_lights()
            blink_lights = True
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            prompt_code_until_correct("Enter disarm code:", "123")
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            reset_lights()
            break  # Stop waiting.


def main():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(RED_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(GREEN_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(BLUE_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=sensor_callback)
    blinkenlights_thread = threading.Thread(target=blinkenlights_thread_callback)
    blinkenlights_thread.start()  # Thread will be stopped by the `quit_event`
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("alarm.mp3")
    try:
        while True:
            loop()
    finally:
        quit_event.set()
        reset_lights()
        GPIO.cleanup()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is too complicated for me. I'm a totally beginner in python3. are there any easier ways?

Comment: This isn't significantly more complex than your original. What are you confused with?

Comment: Fair – I added bits to require code entry. Hope that helps.

Comment: one last question. do you know how to make the LEDs blinking while the alarm sound is playing? @AKX

Comment: I imagined that question might come up. You will need another background thread to manage that, since `input()` is synchronous. I can augment the answer...

Comment: @Renaxツ There we go.